# How to get the amount of each program used in Linux?

Tags: linux, logging

I'm new to Linux.
Now I'm doing a project that I need to find out the time of each program used in a specific period.

Is there any command I can use? Or I need to manually check the system log?

And I found that only recent days of history logs displayed in the log viewer. Is there anyway to get all the logs?

Thanks.

I'm using Fedora.

Answer (score 0):

Back in the day when a computer in every desk was only a dream, computers were too expensive and few companies could afford to buy one - so they just rent some computer time from a provider. My dumb terminal was connected to the host computer over a regular phone line using a modem, at the astonishing speed of 9.6 kbps.

This was the era of [Time-Share](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-sharing). From this time, Unix got process accounting.

See the [Enabling Process Accounting on Linux HOWTO](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Process-Accounting/).